# When function has at most one zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

Let's define $n$-th function $f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ , where as $n$ tends to infinity given functions tends to function $f(x)$.

Also for every $n$ $f_{n}(x)$ has at most one zero.

Here is the question:

When $f(x)$ has at most one zero?

I know that is not true in general for example: $f_{n}(x)=x^{2}+x+\frac{1}{n}$.

But what kind of extra conditions given sequence of functions must satisfy to make it true?

I would like to make this discussion as a brainstorm.

Regards.

Comment: I don't think that your counterexample works. $f_5(x)=x^2+x+\frac{1}{5}$ has two zeros. 

However, you can make the counterexample $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}x$. For every $n$, $f_n(x)$ has exactly one zero, but the limit has infinitely many zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is easier to find a condition for *at least one zero* than for *at most one zero*. See the example of kccu in the comments.

If you talk about a sequence of functions, you should specify in which sence to you consider the convergence. I assume, you say, that $f_n$ converge pointwise to a function $f$, which means
$$
\forall x\in\mathbb R~:~f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x).
$$
But through this definition, you can't controll the zeros of $f$ from the zeros of $f_n$. If $f$ has a zero $z\in\mathbb R$, than none of $f_n$ have to have a zero near $z$ or at all!

A far more trivial example is:
$$
f_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_{\geq 0},~f_n(x)=\frac1n.
$$
Here, you get $f\equiv 0$ and further $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. But none of $f_n$ has a zero, while $f$ has everywhere a zero.

Ok, if you like to have an example, where the functions $f_n$ are in some space like $L^p(\mathbb R)$, you can get it:

Consider an arbitrary function $g\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ such that $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Now define $f_n:=\frac1ng$. Obviously, $f_n$ have no zeros for any $n$ and $f_n$ converge to $f\equiv 0$ in $L^p(\mathbb R)$.

And you can to it far worse! Consider a positive function $g\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ which is nonincreasing in $|x|$ and define $f_n(x):=g(x+n)$. Then you get $f_n\to 0$ pointwise while $\|f_n\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}=\|g\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}\not\to 0$.

All in all, I don't think, there is a simple condition to controll the number of zeros of $f$ from above.

Comment: I think you mean to say "*none* of $f_n$" in the places where you say "*any* of $f_n$".

Comment: You are right. Thanks.